# Need to repeat setTimeout() sections for 30 times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, async-await, settimeout

I am not so good with Javascript but I think that "setTimeout" put its functions on a stack for later execution (which starts just after all code in this given block code executes first).

1. First, I need to wait for all "setTimeout" functions to finish their work. I have also inner "setTimeout" function (as it is in example). ...Don't focus on the quality of this written block...
2. After this whole block of code finish its job, I need to repeat the whole given block again for 30 times. First command in this block is to reset the drawings and then I need to redraw these objects from the beginning again and to do this for 30 successive times.

How can I do this?
"for" command will not help me there because of "setTimeout" functions.

```html
// Reset elements before processing
$('.myClass').remove();

// Fill 'myArray' with elements...

// Iterate through array
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
{
    const time = 800;
    setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(myArray[i], param1, time, param2, param3) }, i * time)                
}

function myFunction(myArrayElement, param1, time, param2, param3) 
{
    // Some logic...
    
    // Define timeStep
    const timeStep = 20;
        
    // Inner iteration
    for (let i = 1; i < 50; i++) 
    {
        doSomething(i);
    }
    
    function doSomething(i) 
    {
        setTimeout(function() 
        {
            // Some inner logic...
        }, timeStep * i);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "this whole block" do you mean the entire snippet or just the "myFunction". I'm very confused after reading your question.

Comment: Use promises and `async`/`await`

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/14666679/ramanan-kalirajan

```js
const myFunction = () => console.log('MyFunction was called');

const repeat = (func, times) => {
  func();
  if (times >= 2) {
    setTimeout(() => repeat(func, times - 1));
  }
};

repeat(myFunction, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` wont help you. `setTimeout` is like adding a delay to the function or the code you want to execute. The best way is try recursion. By sending the no. of times as a input to the method you can use recursion.